# Custom variables in Google Analytics

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics, analytics

I have an application in which I am displaying dynamic advertisements. There are some ads displayed on pages without logging in, and others on pages that you have to log in to access them.

First, I want to be able to track how many clicks have been made on a given ad accessible anonymously.

I added this code to the onclick event of the ad

```
onclick="ga('set', 'dimension1', '@item.Id')" // @item.Id is the Id of the Ad
```

I can see that the event is triggered in the GA Debugger in Chrome, but I cannot see the result in GA even after 24h.

Second, I want to be able to track the Ids of the users who have clicked on the a given ad. And I don't know if this can be done using GA.

An ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Custom Dimensions and Metrics are necessarily connected to an interaction and cannot be sent on their own - they must always be followed by an interaction hit (pageview, event, transaction etc).